# Webview stuck on loading website or cloudfare check

Tags: java, android, webview

Hi am trying to do a simple webview app so that I have a dedicated "app" for a website. Javascript is enabled and most websites load properly except for the ones with pre-web checks like animeflv.net or floatplane.com. Running code on Android 8.0.0

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.floatplane;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.net.http.*;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        String url = "https://floatplane.com/";
        myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.fpWebView);

        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.floatplane">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/fpWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any ideas on how to force loading the page or skip any checks will be appreciated.

Comment: you probably need to change user-agent also. That is just a wild guess

Comment: @Ezra but what is the problem? Any exception/problem/hanging/not loading?

Comment: @Boken in the case of a cloudfare page it will just stay in the cloud screen "wait for 5 seconds while we verify your browser" without any progress at all. The accepted solution fixed that behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String userAgent = System.getProperty( "http.agent" );
Log.e("User agent",userAgent);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Can you please try this solution. Working in my emulator with android version 28.

Comment: That did the trick! maybe the ddos protection just ignored my load requests because it thinked it was a bot. Thanks :D

Comment: Problem might be occurring because of j query and css animation. i think appcache and domstorage did the trick. Welcome @Ezra

Comment: I was having the same issue and setDomStorageEnabled(true) fixed it for me. Thanks!